# Saving NSMutable array to file return NO

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application I need to save NSMutable dictionary in file. dictionary contains NSString key and NSString value.

```
-(NSString*)datafilePath{
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"resourceItemProperties.txt"];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    if(resourceItemProperties && rootViewController.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        BOOL test =  [resourceItemProperties writeToFile:[self datafilePath] atomically:YES];
}}
```

But test always return NO; 
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDocumentationDirectory
```

Nah.

```
NSDocumentDirectory
```

is what you want.

Comment: Your favourite bug, H2C03 :)

Comment: @MikeWeller Fortunately, I even managed to find the duplicate - voting to close as such.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `writeToFile:options:error:` method passing `NSDataWritingAtomic` to the options. You can then use the error output argument to find out why the call fails:

```
NSError *error;
if (![resourceItemProperties writeToFile:[self datafilePath]
                                 options:NSDataWritingAtomic
                                   error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

Comment: but I have NSMutableArray not NSData, which don't have such method

Comment: You can use the NSArchiver to serialise any Cocoa collection to NSData and NSUnarchiver to deserialise it.

Comment: I know, but the method is failing, and to get the error out he needs to call an alternative method.